# c# unsynchronized append text

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, serial-port, task

```
SerialPort s = new SerialPort("COM32");
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    s.DataReceived += dataAction;
}

private void dataAction(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = s.ReadLine();
    File.AppendAllText(recordAllSerialPortPath, data);

    if (data == "ABCD")
        s.WriteLine("aaaa");
    if(data=="aaa")
        File.AppendAllText(loggerPath, data);
}
```

I get data from serial port, and I want to write all the data to `recordAllSerialPortPath`.

additionally I want to answer each line on diffrent way (write to SerailPort or write to logger).

It's most important to answer fast , and the problem now with my code it the append text to `recordAllSerialPortPath` takes time and i do it synchronized , so my code wait until the line write to `recordAllSerialPortPath` and then continue to answer.

If I move the "record" to the end of function that not help because the next line  will wait until I finish to record this line.

How can I record each line but not wait to this in my code.

I know I can do Task.run(()=>File.AppendAllText(recordAllSerialPortPath, data)); But i not sure if it's the right sulution.

I will be happy get some way to fix my problem (advantages and disadvantages)

Comment: Use [WriteAsyn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193364(v=vs.110).aspx) perhaps.

Comment: @CodingYoshi without put await  before of this ? if I use await before WriteAsync so that not help me, If I not put await I can't get resualts/exeption,

Comment: Use a stream method.  Fill.AppendAllText is very slow because it has to 1) Open File 2) Move to end of file 3) write data 4) close file.  Opening a SteamWriter you just will do a write to the stream and the actual writing to the file will take place async in the operating system.  WriteAsyn gives very little improvement.

Comment: @jdweng so you offer to write StreamWriter when to program start and close  it when finish?  when I will write text with StreamWrite my thead(/code) will not wait for this and will continue to next line of code(that what I want)

Comment: There is a byte array (memory) that is part of the stream.  So you are writing to the memory and the and then the operating system is moving the memory into the file asynchronously.  So the time to write to the byte array is very fast and you do not have to wait until the writing to the file is completed.  It happens automatically when using a StreamWriter.

Comment: @jdweng so whay the code wait until AppendAllText finish to write and sw.WriteLine(something) not wait untill finish to write?  and according to you all program that use logger need to use StreamWriter and open it when the program load and close it when program end? like that the c# not need to open+close file each writing? (+sane the pointer on the end of file to append text)

Comment: Just open file once at beginning of app and close at end of app.  Then write new data after old data without all the opening and closing.  Only if more than one app is trying to write to same log do you have to open and close.